# optFederov error in R nTrials must be greater than or equal to the number of columns in expanded X

Tags: r

I am using R program to create a fractional factorial design with AlgDesign package. I have 6 variables with levels 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4. After creating the full factorial design, I use optFederov function to create a fractional factorial design.

But when I write this command,

**set.seed(54321)

> des <- optFederov(~.,qstn,6)**

an error occurs,

**Error in optFederov(~., qstn, 6):
nTrials must be greater than or equal to the number of columns in expanded X**

I tried increasing the number of nTrials. 7,8,10,12,14 - all showed the same error. The function finally could be executed with nTrial=15.

But I need a fractional factorial design of 6 observations, where the nTrial=variable. But I still get the error message mentioned above. How do I solve this problem of the error message?